# Get UITableViewCell from UITableView with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to get a subclassed UITableViewCell (class is called 'MasterCell') from my UITableViewController with an changing IndexPath. Let's say, I'll get the cell at the first row:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
MasterCell *cell = (MasterCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This happens in my viewWillAppear method. Unfortunately, cell is nil while debugging.

I have different cells / rows, where I have to change some values in the viewWillAppear method. Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Do you mean your trying to get a cell from your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, it's a storyboard with a TableViewController. 'self.tableView' is a property (IBOutlet UITableView) connected to the TableView.

Comment: You dont get the cell using indexPath. Give it a reuse identifier in storyboard and use MasterCell *cell = (MasterCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"masterCell"];

Comment: Just to be clear, you are actually trying to access the **second** row in the **first** section by your example. The issue of it being `nil` is possibly due to the cell not being visible (as mentioned by Martin R), **or** because your indexPath is out of range (ie there is no second row in first section of your table).  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @gschandler: You are right, the index being out of range is another possible cause, I forgot to mention that. - But in any case, retrieving the cell "to change some values" is not a good idea.

Comment: The IndexPath was right, but the cell was not visible. That was the reason for returning nil. I can set the value of the UIStepper in my cell now in the below mentioned method. Works fine!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` returns `nil` for cells which are currently not visible.

You should not use the cells to store your model data, because cells are reused when you scroll up or down.

Comment: Thank you so much Darren and Martin R! I can set the initial value (it's a UIStepper indeed which gets its value from a Core Data entity) in the method '- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath'. Works fine!

Comment: How about accessing by 'self.tableView.subviews'?