# get instance of specific row in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So, I think my problem is straightforward but I can't figure out how to do it:
I have UITableView inside of UIViewController. Let's say tableView has 50 cells. So the question is how can I get instance of exactly 3'rd cell from the top (for example). For example I want just to change background color of third cel from the top.
 My code look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
    }

    return cell
}
```

I know this code will not work because cells dequeuing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228953/get-uitableviewcell-from-uitableview-with-cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: do you want that particular cell to be highlighted all the time ?

Comment: Yes. The issue is when I scroll up and down cells are dequeuing and for example 16-th cell is highlighted and so on... But I need just only one cell, 1-st or 2-nd of 3-rd... (doesn't matter) from the top

Comment: Don't try and set cell differences manually. Keep models of your cell attributes and then re-load that cell or the table when something needs to change

Comment: The only thing your code is missing is an `else` on the `if` that resets the background color for all other rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if want to change color in cellforrowAtindexpath then:

```
  if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        //reset your cell to default so dequeue will work correctly
    }
```

/**************/
if out Side that function then

let Cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 1)

Answer (score 1):

You could change the color of the 3rd cell in different ways.

I think, in this case, you're missing the `else` block in order to reset the background for other cells that will dequeue the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct you just need to account for the `else` case.

```
if indexPath.row == 3 {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
} else {
    //reset your cell to default so dequeue will work correctly
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you want the third from the top of the screen then J=just use [visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells)

```
let cell = tableView.visibleCells[2]
```

If you mean you want the third cell in the tableView then your code is almost correct.  The third cell is at row 2, because the first cell is at row 0.  To trigger the change you would call [tableView.reloadRows](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the goal I want achieve. That code doesn't work. I think I should call `let grayCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0))` But I don't know when and where I can get this instance...